# React: state-based rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have the following React component:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isRendered: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="result">
        Rendering result
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Based on the state of `this.state.isRendered`, I want my `<div>` component to **render** if the state is `true`, and **not render** if the state is `false`.

What would be the best way to organize it in React?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check `this.state.isRendered` in the `render`. Here I used a simple AND check. Click on the button to change state and see how it works (snippet takes a short while to run):

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isRendered: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      isRendered
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
      {isRendered &&
        <div className="result">
          Rendering result
        </div>
      }
      <button onClick={() => {this.setState({isRendered: !isRendered})}}>{isRendered? 'Hide' : 'Show'}</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This will still render a div though, albeit an empty one. You can just remove the wrapper div and the brackets around the `this.state.isRendered` to actually not render **anything** though :)

Comment: Wow, so simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using a ternary operator check whether isRendered is true else return null:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isRendered: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {this.state.isRendered ?
        <div className="result">
          Rendering result
        </div> : null
      }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to return `null` or `false` for React components. So, if you don't want anything to get rendered, you could do the following:

```
  ...

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isRendered) return null

    return (
      <div className="result">
        Rendering result
      </div>
    )
  }
```

or, alternatively

```
  ...

  render() {
    return this.state.isRendered && (
      <div className="result">
        Rendering result
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple conditional ternary operator to do this:

```
condition ? if_true_result : if_false_result
```

Your code should be like this:

```
render() {
    const {isRendered} = this.state;
    return isRendered ?
       <div className="result">
         Rendering result
       </div>
     : ''
  }
```

Another official way is following the guidelines about Conditional Rendering in Reactjs document: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish that

```
{ this.state.isRendered ? 
<div className="result">
        This if the isRendered is true
      </div>
: <div className="result">
        This if the isRendered is false
      </div> }
```